# SQLite DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries does not work on real device but works on the emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the following methods count my rows

```
long numRows = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(ourDatabase, "fuel_table");
```

And entries in a column with

```
 long mileagenum = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(ourDatabase, FUEL_DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_MILEAGE);
```

Both methods work fine on the emulator but give errors on the real device...

Any idea whats going wrong?
Thank you.

I get an error log as:-

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.database.DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries
at com.poojag.fuelcheck.FuelStoredInfo.getAvgMileage(FuelStoredInfo.java:252)
at com.poojag.fuelcheck.Prediction.onFocusChange(Prediction.java:199)
at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:2742)
at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:6957)
at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:2565)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3720)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3671)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3649)
at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4445)
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7130)
at android.widget.EditText.onTouchEvent(EditText.java:143)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1750)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1135)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1734)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2216)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1887)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting same problem. is there any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[queryNumEntries with selection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) was introduced in API level 11. Your 2.3.6 device is running API level 10.

You can replace it with a regular `COUNT(*)` selection query, for example:

```
long mileagenum = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(ourDatabase,
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + FUEL_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_MILEAGE, null);
```

Comment: 2.3.6 is API level 10 which is less than 11. `longForQuery` has been there since API level 1.

Comment: Is there any difference in *execution time* between both method.

Comment: @laalto:  Is "DatabaseUtils.longForQuery" still a good choice or has it been deprecated?

Comment: @AJW It has not been deprecated.

Comment: Ok, ty.  Do you know if there is an efficiency advantage to longforQuery or DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries versus using getCount() method?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` i.e. `queryNumEntries()` is more efficient than querying all data and retrieving the row count with `getCount()`. But if you're concerned, measure it on your data whether there's any practical difference.

Comment: @ AJW `queryNumEntries` using `DatabaseUtils.longForQuery` too, so it's the same